# How to use dispose with flutter bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, state, bloc

I have this stateful widget which uses a bloc called `RecorderBloc`:

```
class _RecorderScreenWidgetState extends State<RecorderScreenWidget> {
  late final RecorderBloc _recorderBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _recorderBloc = serviceLocator.get<RecorderBloc>();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _recorderBloc.add(RecorderEvent.dispose());
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                 //.....ommitted code
   }
```

As you can see I need to dispose some members of the bloc after I finish from them, and that is done by adding a dispose event.

But I don't know if defining the bloc as  a member variable of the stateful widget is the right approach?

If not, then how can I get the instance of the bloc inside the `dispose()` method of the `StatefulWidget` to add a dispose event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know there is no need for defining a `dispose` event. The `Bloc` class has a `close` function which will be called when the provider widget (`BlocProvider`) state is being disposed. You can override that function inside of your BLoC and do whatever is needed.

```
class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyBlocState> {
  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    // dispose
    return super.close();
  }
}
```